# Best way to send Videos from the iPhone?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, windows, video, iphone

What is the best way to send a video from the iPhone to another iPhone or to a PC - Windows ?

I tried dropbox but it is really slow (probably because of my internet) .. BUMP doesnt send videos, and I tried itunes but it syncs to "Videos" .. I want the video to appear in the camera roll without the need of using iFile from cydia.

Any ideas ?

Regards.

Comment: this is about jailbreaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a jailbroken device, you can use AirBlue Sharing to send videos over Bluetooth - see [here for the developer's description](http://www.if0rce.com/en/airblue-sharing-2/) and [here for a Lifehacker post about it](http://lifehacker.com/5884586/airblue-sharing-transfers-files-over-bluetooth-on-jailbroken-iphones).

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing to another iPhone within 10 feet, use the AirDrop feature, which is sent through Bluetooth. If not, select each photo and tap the up arrow in a box at the bottom left corner and choose mail.